# Stopping std::vector from calling d'tors when out of scope

Tags: c++, stl

I am porting some Java to C++ and rather naively jumped in to using `std::vector`.

Here is my problem. I have a repository of objects and at some point later I will require
a list of objects from this repository that satisfy some condition. Currently I am reading them into a temporary `std::vector`. It turns out that when this temporary goes out of scope
it'll `delete` its contents and of course that'll lead to dangling pointers in the repository.

This is my current 'workaround', that I find particularly disgusting.

```
#define NULLIFY(aParam) \
{ \
    for (size_t i = 0; i < aParam.size(); i++) { \
        aParam[i] = NULL; \
    } \
}

typedef std::vector<Object*> TObjectVector;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PopulateRepository(); // repository uses std::set

    TObjectVector subset;
    Repository.GetConditionSatisfyingObjects(subset);
    DoSomething(subset);

    NULLIFY(subset); // Stop destruction of the objects.
}
```

I'm open to other ideas. I did originally have it all working with raw pointers and dynamic allocation but I wanted to see if there was a speed-up with using STL as I'd have less parameters to pass around. The program is multithreaded and quite CPU intensive.

Comment: You didn't ask this, but you should try std::shared_ptr (c++11), formerly in std::tr1, if you are porting java code. Java employs garbage collection, and it's a tricky thing to convert it to c++, without causing any memory leaks.

Comment: @EvanDark Yes I'd like to do that but VC++ 2010 doesn't support it. I'm having massive issues figuring out object lifetimes. Edit: it seems it knows about std::tr1

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using `new` to allocate space and `delete` to free it? Nullifying a pointer doesn't release the memory in C++.

Comment: @DigitalDa Yes sure. I wanted it to stop it freeing because I misunderstood how it worked!

Comment: @James: VS 2010 also supports std::shared_ptr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a vector of pointers such as `std::vector<Object*>`, the `Object` destructors will *not* be called.

And if you have a vector of objects, such as `std::vector<Object>`, then you store *copies* of whatever gets "put" in the vector. So I am not sure where the dangling pointers could come from.

Comment: Ok, I must be overthinking things and misread some other posts when I was reading up about how it works. Thanks